# Can anyone share an idea about how to share image from ImageView in ViewPager using UIL library?

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, android-sharing

Am using UIL library to display my images in viewpager and as well as for also zooming the images.In that I want to add a share button to share the images to fb,gmail,twitter,whatsapp etc., in that when i tried to share an image from the page means it is sharing the next image not the selected one.How can i rectify this in UIL?

This is my code snippet for image loader..

```
private class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public ImageAdapter() {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
         View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_pager_image, view, false);
        assert imageLayout != null;
        TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.loading);
        ivImage = (ImageView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                String message = null;
                switch (failReason.getType()) {
                    case IO_ERROR:
                        message = "Input/Output error";
                        break;
                    case DECODING_ERROR:
                        message = "Image can't be decoded";
                        break;
                    case NETWORK_DENIED:
                        message = "Downloads are denied";
                        break;
                    case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                        message = "Out Of Memory error";
                        break;
                    case UNKNOWN:
                        message = "Unknown error";
                        break;
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is to get the image url just i have done by sample values

```
String[] imageurls={
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7-EHhtQthII/URqvEYTk4vI/AAAAAAAAAbs/QSJZoB3YjVg/s1024/Tenaya%252520Lake%2525202.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-8MrjV_a-Pok/URqvFC5repI/AAAAAAAAAbs/9inKTg9fbCE/s1024/Tenaya%252520Lake.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-B1HW-z4zwao/URqvFWYRwUI/AAAAAAAAAbs/8Peli53Bs8I/s1024/The%252520Cave%252520BW.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PO4E-xZKAnQ/URqvGRqjYkI/AAAAAAAAAbs/42nyADFsXag/s1024/The%252520Fisherman.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-iLyZlzfdy7s/URqvG0YScdI/AAAAAAAAAbs/1J9eDKmkXtk/s1024/The%252520Night%252520is%252520Coming.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-G-k7YkkUco0/URqvHhah6fI/AAAAAAAAAbs/_taQQG7t0vo/s1024/The%252520Road.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-h-ALJt7kSus/URqvIThqYfI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ejiv35olWS8/s1024/Tokyo%252520Heights.jpg",
        "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Hy9k-TbS7xg/URqvIjQMOxI/AAAAAAAAAbs/RSpmmOATSkg/s1024/Tokyo%252520Highway.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-83oOvMb4OZs/URqvJL0T7lI/AAAAAAAAAbs/c5TECZ6RONM/s1024/Tokyo%252520Smog.jpg",
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-FB-jfgREEfI/URqvJI3EXAI/AAAAAAAAAbs/XfyweiRF4v8/s1024/Tufa%252520at%252520Night.jpg",
        "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-vngKD5Z1U8w/URqvJUCEgPI/AAAAAAAAAbs/ulxCMVcU6EU/s1024/Valley%252520Sunset.jpg",
        "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-DOz5I2E2oMQ/URqvKMND1kI/AAAAAAAAAbs/Iqf0IsInleo/s1024/Windmill%252520Sunrise.jpg"};
```

And this is for sharing the image by clicking the share button

```
btnshare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onShareItem();
            }
        }); 
public void onShareItem() {
    // Get access to bitmap image from view
    // Get access to the URI for the bitmap
    Uri bmpUri = getLocalBitmapUri(ivImage);
    if (bmpUri != null) {
        // Construct a ShareIntent with link to image
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "default");
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        // Launch sharing dialog for image
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image"));    
    } else {
        // ...sharing failed, handle error
    }
}
public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(ImageView imageView) {
    // Extract Bitmap from ImageView drawable
    Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
       bmp = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    } else {
       return null;
    }
    // Store image to default external storage directory
    Uri bmpUri = null;
    try {
        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(  
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Comment: show code snippet when you share image.

Comment: i have changed my question take a look in that.